# How to configure new disk for UEFI boot using grub2

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I am using an ASUS N53J that is currently using MBR boot.  I have enabled UEFI booting in the bios can can seem to boot USB drives that have been configured with gpt tables.  Though I have not figured out how to make use of a dedicated EFI boot partition on the USB drive as yet.

Separately I have connected a second  hdd to the laptop via the external SATA connection, created a gpt partition table, esp boot partition, and the filesystem and swap partitions.

When I run `grub-mkconfig` on the internal hdd, it finds the new linux image on the external hdd.  I can boot to that external image and confirm that the esp boot partition gets mounted at `/boot/efi`, so it appears that I should be able to configure grub2.  However, if I run `grub-mkconfig` when executing from the external drive, its own image does not get found, only the linux and windows images on the internal drive.

I also cannot get `efibootmgr` to run.  The tutorials I have read either are not clear on both the how and the why so I can troubleshoot myself or use commands that I cannot find in the packages I think they are using.  Does anyone have a good pointer on how to configure the disk before I install it as the primary boot disk?

Thanks.

Update 2015-12-30
I have progressed to making a USB drive that will at least boot into grub rescue.  I do not know why grub won't run from this drive but it at least allows me to manually boot  to my target OS.  Since I have now booted via a UEFI boot `efibootmgr` is available.

I performed a new grub-install targeting the esp partition mounted at `/boot/efi`.  This completed without errors.  However, when I select the target system for booting the firmware loader stops at a blank screen.  This occurs whether the disk is connected via ESATA or has been moved to be the primary disk in the machine.

the output of `efibootmgr -v` is:

```
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0005,0002,0003,0004,0000,0001
Boot0000  Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)
Boot0001  CD/DVD Drive  BBS(CDROM,,0x0)P1: Slimtype BD  E  DS4E1S    .
Boot0002* ubuntu 15.10  HD(1,GPT,8b6800c2-0b24-4f00-aa66-b1378052604e,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\bootx64.efi)
Boot0003* grub  HD(2,GPT,b07e72fd-9168-4924-a17c-b75e55ed685c,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\Shellx64.efi)
Boot0004* UEFI: SanDisk Cruzer Micro 1.26   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/USB(1,0)/USB(2,0)/HD(2,GPT,b07e72fd-9168-4924-a17c-b75e55ed685c,0x800,0xfa000)
Boot0005* ubuntu15.10   HD(1,GPT,8b6800c2-0b24-4f00-aa66-b1378052604e,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu15.10\grubx64.efi)
```

The desired target is `Boot0005`.  `Boot0002` is an experiment copying `grubx64.efi` to `/boot/efi/bootx64.efi`.  Both `Boot0002` and `Boot0005` behave similarly.

`Boot0003` (grub) is the USB drive and the only means to boot, though it only starts in grub rescue.

Any ideas where I should explore or what additional information may assist diagnosis?

**More progress:**

```
grub rescue> set  
prefix=(hd0,2)/boot/grub  ... This is the fat32-formatted esp boot partition  

grub rescue>ls (hd0,2)/  
unknown filesystem      ... or similar words to that effect

grub rescue>set prefix=(hd0,1)/boot/grub  ... ext4-formatted partition
grub rescue> insmod fat
grub rescue>ls (hd0,2)/
                    .... the directory is now read
```

setting the root to the target boot system and the prefix to the /boot/grub directory of that target system I can `insmod linux` search config file and normal.  If normal does not start the boot option page the following will:

```
grub rescue>configfile /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

I can eventually get the target to boot from the menu.

My synopsis is that `grubx64.efi` on the USB drive is not configured with the necessary modules for the boot method being used.

While efi-booted into my target filesystem I created a new USB drive, also with a gpt partition table, this time with esp boot as partition 1.  I only mention that to assist with reading the bios boot table presented later.

mounting USB partition 2 to an appropriate node:

```
mkdir -p /boot/efi
```

mount (USB partition 1) to (USB partition 2)/boot/efi

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=(USB partition 2)/boot/efi --removable
```

generates `EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI`.  The UEFI: Sandisk entry in the bios  boot table is the means to boot via this loader

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=(USB partition2)/boot/efi --bootloader-id=USBboot
```

generates `EFI/USBboot/grubx64.efi`.  The USBboot entry is also written int the bios boot table

`cmp -v BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI USBboot/grubx64.efi` yields no differences
either boot option now boots directly to the target filesystem without displaying any grub boot menu.  Since the USB drive does not have a `/boot/grub` directory or a `grub.cfg`, `grubx64.exe` must be configured to search for this directory on the target rather than USB.

```
$ efibootmgr -v
BootOrder: 0007,0004,0005,0002,0003,0008,0000,0001
Boot0000  Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)
Boot0001  CD/DVD Drive  BBS(CDROM,,0x0)P1: Slimtype BD  E  DS4E1S    .
Boot0002* ubuntu 15.10  HD(1,GPT,8b6800c2-0b24-4f00-aa66-b1378052604e,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\bootx64.efi)
Boot0003* grub  HD(2,GPT,b07e72fd-9168-4924-a17c-b75e55ed685c,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\Shellx64.efi)
Boot0004* ubuntu_15_10  HD(1,GPT,8b6800c2-0b24-4f00-aa66-b1378052604e,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu_15_10\grubx64.efi)
Boot0005* ubuntu15.10   HD(1,GPT,8b6800c2-0b24-4f00-aa66-b1378052604e,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu15.10\grubx64.efi)
Boot0007* USBboot   HD(1,GPT,f887bf87-18a9-40e1-9bca-6c4bfd1cbb4a,0x800,0xc8000)/File(\EFI\USBboot\grubx64.efi)
Boot0008* UEFI: SanDisk PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/USB(1,0)/USB(4,0)/HD(1,GPT,f887bf87-18a9-40e1-9bca-6c4bfd1cbb4a,0x800,0xc8000)
```

I still have not figured out how to even get to grub rescue without booting from the external USB drive.  Is seems as though I have two problems:

1. I don't fully understand how to configure grub for its intended use, how to make sure necessary modules are built in and the prefix is properly set.
2. I either do not have the bios on the ASUS N53J properly configured or it is not accepting the hard disk configuration as a valid boot configuration.

**Any other ideas?  I now this is getting rather long.  How can I document this to be more readable?**

**Status Update**

Browsing on the web I have discovered `grub-mkimage`.  I have not started working with this and will report progress once I have done so and can either understand the results or can pose a new question about it.

Comment: What errors do you get from running sudo efibootmgr?

Comment: Grub only wants to install to sda. But if sda is a MBR(msdos) drive it has issues. And external drives in UEFI only boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. So you have to make/rename grub to bootx64.efi. If grub not installed you may need to just directly install it from live installer.

Comment: error is "EFI variables are not supported on this system".  I gather that this means that the bootloader on /dev/sda loaded from the MBR and not an esp, which I'm  pretty confident is what is happening.

Comment: I take renaming grub to mean the grub executable.  Is this  "grub.efi", which I currently find at /boot/efi/EFI/grub?            For clarity, how is a drive connected to an ESATA port distinguished from the drive connected internally to SATA, other than the SATA port number?

Comment: Usually the signed grub executable is found in /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx63.efi, but check its size against the "source" in  /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi-signed/grubx64.efi.signed.  Blank screen may be a video problem, if you have Nvidia then lots of things like nomodeset on the grub kernel line  to try.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with other hdd's I have determined my problems appear to be related to the esp,boot partition on the original hdd.  When I originally made the esp,boot partition I had accepted the default offset of 1 MB suggested by gparted.  Through exploring why I could boot from USB drives and another hard drive connected via ESATA the common attribute on the successful media was the esp,boot partition being 1st on the drive and with 0 offset.

My attempt at moving the esp,boot partition was not successful.  However, I did not check to make sure the UUID and PARTUUID were not modified so I do not know if this failure was due to the move not configuring the disk so the BIOS could figure out how to read it or if I failed by not re-configuring grub.

In any case, I learned how to:
 properly move the filesystem to new hdd
 configure the problem hdd from scratch.
 move the filesystem back
 modify `/etc/fstab` to reflect the new UUID's for mounted partitions
 the esp,boot partition had a copy of Shellx64.efi in its root directory

I then:
  reinstalled the hdd into the internal drive bay
  started the system in BIOS setup mode
  initiated `Shellx64.efi` from BIOS
  typed "c" to get to the grub prompt

```
grub> linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda2
grub> initrd /initrd.img
grub> boot
```

This started the filesystem (as it always would previously if I had a means to get to grub). This time when I grub-install and `grub-mkconfig` and  reboot, the BIOS can read `grubx64.efi` from the proper location on esp,boot partition.  Success!